# JSON data not added in jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

JSON data not added in jQuery array

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("automcomplete.php", function(data, status) {
      console.log(data);
      // echo json_encode($result['name']);
      // response 
      // "Afghanistan""Africa""Albania""Algeria"

      var availableTags = [data];
      // i want todo this 
      // var availableTags = [
      //    "america",
      //    "london"
      //   ];
      $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Create auto complete list dynamically and show in the list problem is how i can put json data in jquery array

Comment: I wonder why do u have both  `$(function(){})` and `$(document).ready()`; they are one and the same. and directly assign data to availableTags

Comment: Also add `dataType` argument or use `$.getJSON` to be sure `data` is parsed

Comment: Show the php. Looks like you might have multiple `echo` in a loop and need to create an array and only echo once

Comment: @RahulNaik i am new in jquery so did not notice

Comment: @charlietfl only single echo if (isset($result_array)) {
  foreach ($result_array as $result) {     

     echo json_encode($result['name']
       );
  }}

Comment: No...that is multiple echo ... once per iteration of the loop. That does not produce valid json. In the loop do `$outputArray[] = $result['name'];` then after loop ... `echo json_encode($outputArray);`

Comment: Can you plz tell me  i put echo after closing tag of foreach than my reponse like this ["Afghanistan","Africa"] how i assgin it to jquery array and it show  like this var result = ["Afghanistan","Afghanistan"]; instead of var result = [["Afghanistan","Afghanistan"]];

Comment: You send an array from the server and pass that array to the plugin as shown below in answer

Comment: thanks man its works i put echo after foreach than use @Rory McCrossan code its works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code indicates that you're returning JSON, so you can just remove `var availableTags = [data];` and give `data` directly to the `source` property:

```
$(function() {
  $.get("automcomplete.php", function(data) {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: data
    });
  });
});
```

If your data is returned as a string, you can manually parse it to an object using `JSON.parse()`:

```
$.get("automcomplete.php", function(data) {
  var sourceData = JSON.parse(data);
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: sourceData
  });
});
```

Note that you don't need two document.ready handlers. A single `$(function() {});` is enough

Comment: That's down to what your server returns. Presumably you need to amend the AJAX so you can send the search term and then your `automcomplete.php` should perform the search logic.

Comment: my repsonse is "Afghanistan""Africa""Albania""Algeria"  and i need reponse like this "Afghanistan","Africa","Albania","Algeria" but how i add comma after every single country i think thats why its not work perfect